# Parse web url and have key value pair

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing, query-string

I wan to parse following URL.

```
http://testurl?k=firstname%3AA%20department%3AIT%20Development%20Company%3ATest%20Company

http://testurl?k=department%3AIT%20Development%20firstname%3AA%20Company%3ATest%20Company
```

%3A = ':'

%20 = ' '

```
http://testurl?k=firstname:A department:IT Development Company:Test Company
http://testurl?k=department:IT Development firstname:A Company:Test Company
```

What I want is to have key value pair as shown below.

FirstName = A, Department = IT Development, Company = Test Company

Department = IT Development, FirstName = A, Company = Test Company

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Are you trying to parse it in JS or C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JS solution, I would generalize it a bit more (for example, getting the `k` url param value properly)

```
var url = 'http://testurl?k=firstname%3AA%20department%3AIT%20Development%20Company%3ATest%20Company';
var args = unescape(url).split('?k=')[1];
args = args.split(/\s+(?=\w+:)/);

var results = {};
for (i in args) {
  keyval = args[i].split(':');
  results[keyval[0]] = keyval[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it gave me following result. args[0]='firstname' args[1]='A department'. I need map firstname with A only.

Comment: @ashish.chotalia The output is in `results`, not `args`

Comment: Yups, In results I have results[firstname]="A deparment" and results[IT Development Company]="Conference Room". I need to have something like results[firstname]="A" results[department]="IT development" results[company]="conference room". Thanks

Comment: @ashish.chotalia Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Revised my answer to fit it

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the code generating your URLs, then I would recommend that you alter it to introduce a delimiter between your key–value pairs. As it stands, it is hard to distinguish where a value ends and the next key starts.

Here is the solution step-by-step.

First, extract the query string from your URL (which I will assume to reside in `urlString`):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(urlString);
NameValueCollection outer = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

Due to the way it is encoded, your query string technically only contains a single key–value pair, with the key being `k`. The rest of your key–value pairs are encoded *within* the value for `k`. Thus, we shall get that value and decode it:

```
string k = outer["k"];
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(k);
```

The next part is the trickiest: extracting your keys and values. We shall use regex for matching these:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(decoded, @"(?<key>\w+):(?<value>.*?)(?= \w+:|$)");
```

We shall assume that your keys consist only of word characters (letters, digits, and underscores); thus, they would be matched by `(?<key>\w+)`. Each key is followed by a `:` character. Next, the values may consist of any sequence of characters, `(?<value>.*?)`. However, they must be followed either by another key, `\w+:`, or the end of the string, `$`; thus, we will use a positive lookahead for matching either of these.

Finally, just convert any matches to a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = matches.Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(
    m => m.Groups["key"].Value, 
    m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Combined, this would give you:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(urlString);
NameValueCollection outer = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
string k = outer["k"];
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(k);
var matches = Regex.Matches(decoded, @"(?<key>\w+):(?<value>.*?)(?= \w+:|$)");
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = matches.Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(
    m => m.Groups["key"].Value, 
    m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Comment: Douglas, Thanks for the solution. I will upvote this cause this also worked.

Comment: Thanks! Dor Shemer gave the correct code first, so he deserves to have his answer chosen as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start in C#:

```
string MyUrl = "http://testurl?k=firstname%3AA%20department%3AIT%20Development%20Company%3ATest%20Company";

MyUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(MyUrl);
```

You should be able to use String.Split after that.

Comment: This give me output like "firstname:A department:IT Development Company:Conference Rooms". I want to have key value pair. What I have is firstname, department and company as textbox where I need to fill out these values.